# Отображение списочных данных в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

С С# я знаком относительно недавно, всегда занимался веб-программированием.

Появилось желание написать десктопное приложение для одного файлообменника. Форму построил, `json` ответ получил, все окей. Пришло все это вывести список моих файлов на в форму.

Если бы я все это выводил на сайте (основываясь на предыдущем опыте) я бы это вывел в красивой таблице с использованием `<div>` блоков. Но в c# так не получится. Хотя нет, получится, но взглянув на `DataGridView` я ужаснулся, и понял, что нужно искать другой способ, но какой? В интернете все только и пишут об этом `DataGridView`.

Вот так выводится список файлов на сайте, но я не понимаю, как сделать так же красиво с помощью `Windows Form` не используя страшный `DataGridView`.

Буду рад любым предложениям.
[image: Список файлов]

Comment: Хотите красивый дизайн - используйте `WPF`. В нем в разы удобней это реализовывать и понятным для `Web` разработчика языком, `XAML`, который в свою очередь очень напоминает `HTML`.

Comment: Для Web-разработчика WPF будет понятнее, имхо. Но не стремитесь использовать сразу кроваво-энтерпрайзный DataGrid, стройте из маленьких кусочков в ItemsControl или ListBox

Comment: Не знал об WPF. Спасибо